# BDC Incremental crawl always crawls full

Tags: external-content-type, crawl, bdc

I added External Content Type to my BCD application. The content type gets data from SAP trough a service.

There is a column/property in the service called `PartnerChangeDate`, that is set to last change on specific "partner entity.

```
  <TypeDescriptor Name="PartnerChangeDate" DefaultDisplayName="PartnerChangeDate" 
                  TypeName="System.DateTimeOffset">
    <Interpretation>
      <ConvertType LOBType="System.DateTimeOffset" BDCType="System.DateTime" />
      <NormalizeDateTime LobDateTimeMode="UTC" />
    </Interpretation>
  </TypeDescriptor>
```

Within the `MethodInstance` I've set the property as a timestamp:

```
<MethodInstances>
<MethodInstance Name="ReadAllContactPerson" Type="Finder" Default="true" 
      ReturnParameterName="@ContactPersons" ReturnTypeDescriptorPath="ContactPersons">
  <Properties>
    <Property Name="RootFinder" Type="System.String" />
    <Property Name="LastModifiedTimeStampField" Type="System.String">
        PartnerChangeDate
    </Property>
  </Properties>
```

However, when I crawl this source, even incremental crawl indexes all entities in service, instead of just few that have changed:

[image]

What did I set wrong with the timestamp? How can I fix this?